# cannot upload the image on server using php

Tags: php

I form when i select the image and then click upload now its only execute " please select a file" please check for error as i could not figure it out.
    
    
     uploading files
    
    
    
     
     
    
    Upload a file:
    
    
    enter code here
    Click upload now

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name=@$_FILES=['file']['name'];
    $type=@$_FILES=['file']['type'];
    $size=@$_FILES=['file']['size'];
    $tmp=@$_FILES=['file']['tmp_name'];
    if($name=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('please select a file') </script>";
        exit();
    }
    if(($type =="image/jpeg")||($type =="image/gif") ||($type =="image/png"))
    {
        if(file_exists("images/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo"this file $name is already exist";
            exit();
        }
        if($size<=5000)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp,"images/$name");
            echo "file was uploaded <img src='imges/$name'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Size of image $size is larger then 50 kb";
        }
    }else
    {
        echo "$type This is not valid";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@$_FILES=['file'][...];` why did you put `=` sign there? And don't suppress errors by prepending `@`.

Comment: ohh thanks i sort this out = sign was the problem @ i put because its gives me error for under defined but now its ok